# Why is this a basis for the subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

A subspace $\mathcal{U}$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by the plane with equation $x-2y+z=0$. Letting $y = s$ and $z = t$, we have $x = 2s - t$ and all vectors $(x,y,z)$ in $\mathcal{U}$ can be given by 
$$
\left[\begin{array}{r}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{array}\right]
=
s
\left[\begin{array}{r}
2\\
1\\
0
\end{array}\right]
+ t
\left[\begin{array}{r}
-1\\
0\\
1
\end{array}\right]
$$
Hence a basis for $\mathcal{U}$ is
$$
\mathcal{B} = \{\left[\begin{array}{r}
2\\
1\\
0
\end{array}\right], \left[\begin{array}{r}
-1\\
0\\
1
\end{array}\right]\}
$$
Now it is given that an orthogonal basis for $\mathcal{U}$ is
$$
\mathcal{O} =
\{
\left[\begin{array}{r}
2\\
1\\
0
\end{array}\right]
,
\left[\begin{array}{r}
-0.2\\
0.4\\
1
\end{array}\right]
\}
$$
How do I show that $\mathcal{O}$ is also a basis for $\mathcal{U}$? Because I cannot see how to derive that from the plane equation that defines the subspace (because the second component in the vector scaled by $t$ is $0$).

Comment: They are linearly independent over a subspace of dimension 2, both of which satisfy the equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the following things:

1. Vectors in $O$ are linearly independent.
2. It's dimension is $2$.
3. And all vectors in $U$ can be formed using a linear combination of the vectors given in $O$.

Comment: Isn't number 3 sufficient? Like, it implies the others?

Comment: I wrote down all properties of $O$ that pointed to it being the basis of $U$. 1 and 2 are sufficient in itself. Number 3 is not sufficient in itself. Linear Independence is required. So 1 and 3 will be alright.

Comment: But can't you find two linearly independent vectors that does not define a basis for $\mathcal{U}$?

Comment: Yes you can. $1$ vector subspace is independent and in this case won't be a basis. That's why I wrote $1$ and $2$ are sufficient in themselves. $1$ is not sufficient in itself.

Comment: Ah okay. But just to get this straight: Having dimension 2 just implies that there are two vectors in the basis - so having *two* (dimension 2) linearly independent vectors satisfies point 1 and 2. So I cannot see why their combination changes the answer to whether "But can't you find two (satisfying point 2) linearly independent vectors (i.e. satisfying point 1) that does not define a basis for U?" or not? Please elaborate :)))

Comment: Linearly independent subset of size $2$ will be a basis in this case. If it weren't, there would exist a vector $u$ that is not a linear combination of the $2$ said vectors, i.e, $u$ would be another linearly independent vector. But we know that the dimension of the basis is $2$ so our claim that it's not a basis is contradicted.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I have accepted your answer now. However, one final thing: You say "Linearly independent subset of size 2" - subset of what?

Comment: Subspace of $U$. Shouldn't have used subset

Answer (score 1):

It  should be clear that the vectors in $\mathcal O$ are linearly independent since one of the vectors has a null component, whereas the other has not.

Also, both vectors satisfy the  equation $x-2y+z=0$, and the subspace defined by this equation has codimension $1$, hence dimension $2$ in a $3$-dimensional space, so a set of $2$ linearly independent vectors is a basis.

Comment: "so a set of 2 linearly independent vectors is a basis" - but does one of the linearly independent vectors have to be one of the vectors in $\mathcal{B}$? If so, why, or why not? Thanks!

Comment: No, it doesn't. *Any* set of $n$ linearly independent vectors in a space of dimension $n$ is a basis.

Answer (score 0):

Solve the system

$$\begin{pmatrix}-\frac15\\\frac25\\1\end{pmatrix}=s\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}+t\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2s-t\\s\\t\end{pmatrix}$$

Check the above is soluble and that's all...

Comment: Oh, but why $\frac{4}{5}$? Is it a typo?

Comment: @f Yes, of course it is. Thanks, edited.

Comment: I just tried to calculate $s$ and $t$ myself by solving the augmented matrix $$ \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} -2&-1&-1/5\\ 1&0&2/5
\\ 0&1&1\end {array} \right] 
$$, however, I get $$ \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 1&0&2/5\\ 0&1&-3/5
\\ 0&0&8/5\end {array} \right]
$$ which is inconsistent? Why? If it was a linear combination of the two vectors (a basis of $\mathcal{U}$), this should not have happened?

Comment: Can you please help me out with the above. If you do, you have officially saved my day :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you need help with: if you do the operations on the center, you get the right side. Now compare it to the left side and get trivially that $$s=\frac25\,,\,\,t=1$$and thus you get that

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=(2,1,0)$ and $v=(-1,0,1)$.

If you use "Gram-Schmidt" to get an orthogonal vector to $u$ using the vector $v$, you get

$$w=v-\frac{v\cdot u}{u\cdot u} u=(-1,0,1)-\frac{-2}{5}(2,1,0)=(-\frac{1}{5},\frac{2}{5},1)=(-0.2,0.4,1)$$

So, you can see, that since $w$ is a (non-trivial) linear combination of $u,v$, then $\{u,w\}$ is also a basis of your space. Even more, the way we constructed $w$ gives you that this is an orthogonal basis, of course you can also see this just by checking $u\cdot w=0$.